# How to change the jquery mmenu to open from the right?

Tags: jquery, user-experience, mmenu

I'm trying to create a custom behaviour to mmenu to open from the right side of the website.

There is any guide on how to change such thing? Here is what I got so far.

http://codepen.io/davo/pen/krxLw

Anyway, I'll keep working on this, if I find a proper way, I'll post it here.

Comment: Rather than sharing your entire codebase, if you isolate the part of the code where you are trying to accomplish this behavior you'll make it easier for people to help you. Consider putting that code directly into the question for posterity's sake.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out to get the etiquette here.

Comment: How is this off-topic?

Comment: Off-Topic? What are you talking about? It is right on topic, I need this answered too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the option `position`. Default it is `left` but if you set it to `right` your menu slides open from the right. Add `direction:'right'` so it opens to the left.

```
$menu.mmenu({
    dragOpen: true,
    position:'right',
    direction:'left',
    ...
});
```

And no, there doesn't really seem to be documentation about this plugin. I have just downloaded the source code and had a look how it all works. That's how I found out.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It helped, thanks.

Actually I had to change some parts of the CSS on the mmenu.css.


#header a,
.header a
{
 display: block;
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 10px;
}

Comment: Shame this question is closed; it's definitely relevant.  Anyhow, there's now a plug-in to handle positioning: http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/documentation/extensions/positioning.html.

Comment: ^ Not a plugin, but an extension of the plugin itself

Answer (score 2):

Set the option "position" to "right" ("direction" isn't an option):

```
$("nav").mmenu({
    offCanvas {
        position: "right"
    }
});
```

The documentation for the plugin comes with the download pack, just open the docs/index.html file for examples, the options, the events and a tutorial. All of this is also accessible via the website (click the "check out these pages" links).

EDIT:
Plugin is now properly documented: http://mmenu.frebsite.nl

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working. {position:'right'} still slides the menu left - right. Anything I've tried doesn't change the behavior. Can you please provide an example that does this, since it's a feature that others may need as well? Thanks.

Comment: @IIS7Rewrite the solution would be to use it within the `offCanvas` object. See [this](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/documentation/extensions/positioning.html) for more details.